# VBA Excel 2010 - Runtime error '1004' Application-defined or object-deined error

Tags: vba, excel

**EDIT:**

So, it appears my excel document contain my code has corrupted thus causes the quite unusual problem, I thank you all for the help you have given. This has been resolved by moving all macros and sheets into a new excel document

The code below will get the error message "Runtime error '1004' Application-defined or object-deined error" at `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select` at the bottom but when it is run the code also doesnt run the `[C7].Select` part either (but there is no error message at this point)

I have tried using, `Range("C7").select` and `Cells(7,3).select` which also dont work. I have also tried `Application.Wait` to see if the macro may have been too fast however this also doesnt resolve the issue, I have removed the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and again this doesnt work.

I have tried this macro on 4 different PCs and 2 different versions of excel and all have the same issue.

**EDIT:**

Just to clear things up as I think my explination above may be a bit unclear

The problem is currently with this section of code

```
[C7].Select
'Do Until ActiveCell.Row >= Finalrow
'drop out of loop if no more dates detected in row 3
Do Until sName = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

What happens when I run the code to this part of the code is the error message above will appear at `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select` this line, however `[C7].Select` also does not select cell C7 (it remains at the cell that was already selected).

What is supposed to happen is that it runs down the cells in column C looking at column A until it reachs the persons name (defined by `sName`), once it gets to that is will then run the rest of the code (that I havent posted at I cant get further than this point, I can post the whole thing if requested)

---

```
Option Compare Text
Public sLeave As Integer, iAnnualLeave As Integer, sLeaveType As String

Sub LeaveChecker()

Dim iAnnualLeave As Integer

bTrackingLeave = False
bReachedEndOfChart = False
bStartDateFound = False

'Set Color with If Statement



sTypeOfLeave = [D12].Value

If sTypeOfLeave = "Annual Leave" Then
sLeaveType = "AL"
ElseIf sTypeOfLeave = "Flexi Leave" Then
sLeaveType = "FL"
sLeaveTypeAmPm = "FL???"

ElseIf sTypeOfLeave = "Special Leave" Then
sLeaveType = "SpL"
ElseIf sTypeOfLeave = "Study Leave" Then
sLeaveType = "StL"
ElseIf sTypeOfLeave = "Meeting/Traning" Then
sLeaveType = "M/T"
End If

'Check to see if type of leave is populated
If sTypeOfLeave = "" Then
MsgBox ("Please Populate Type Of Leave")
End If




Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Find last sheet name
Set ws = Sheets(Sheets.Count)
sLastSheet = ws.Name

sName = [M3].Value

If sName = "" Then
MsgBox ("Please Enter A Staff Members Name")
Exit Sub
End If

Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate

SearchNewSheet:

If ActiveSheet.Name = sLastSheet Then
bReachedEndOfChart = True
GoTo LastStage
End If

Do Until ActiveSheet.Name = sLastSheet 'Main   LOOP~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

If bReachedEndOfChart = True Then GoTo FinalGather

'Find Person Name


[C7].Select
'Do Until ActiveCell.Row >= Finalrow
'drop out of loop if no more dates detected in row 3
Do Until sName = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

Comment: "bugs out". What does it do? If it throws an error, whats the error?

Comment: You should put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and declare all of your variables. Such heavy use of undeclared variables is a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: You're probably trying to select a cell below the last available one, as you have no controls for stopping the loop if the name doesn't match.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The error I get is "Runtime error '1004' Application-defined or object-deined error" and then just stops but if i use F8 to step through it, it will work

Comment: @Rory I neglected to mention this is my question but the code bugs out at the origional cell that was selected, so if A1 was selected befor ethe code was run it will remain there at the point it bugs out regardless of the [C7].select

Comment: You turned off screen updating, so it would appear that way even if another cell was selected.

Comment: you say in your comment you want to check row 3, but you are using the `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select` to go one row below. If you want to check row 3, you need to offest the Column like `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select`.

Comment: @JohnColeman, Just used Options Explicit and cleaned up the undeclared variables, still the same issue

Comment: @Rory , As mentioned in the question I removed screen updating and still have the same issue

Comment: First, please stop saying bugs out and tell us the actual error. Second, you said the error comes at the `activecell.offset` line, not the `[C7].Select` line. Which is it?

Comment: @Rory First I have given the full error in my first comment to Nick.McDermaid. Second the error message appears at `activecell.offset`

Comment: @JohnColeman actually `[C7].Select` works fine - but correct that it's better to avoid using `Select`.

Comment: @nekomatic I just realized that -- I was used to thinking of things like [C7] as being an alias for the value, but apparently it can work as an object reference as well. I don't really use that syntax. Thanks.

Comment: Would love to know the reson for the downvote so I can improve my question

Comment: Possible someone downvoted because this is [not an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: When the error occurs, press debug, open the Immediate window (Ctrl+G) and type: `?Activecell.address` and press Enter. What is the result?

Comment: @Rory , It comes up with $A$33

Comment: Is the worksheet protected? Do you have a ScrollArea set?

Comment: @Rory , The sheet isnt protected, I dont know what a scrollarea is so as a default I would say no

Comment: Can you put a workbook somewhere that shows the problem? I can't see why that line would be a problem given your responses so far. (As an aside though, you really need to learn to code without `Select` and `Goto`.)

Comment: @Rory , Unfortunally this is a work document (and on a work PC) so I cant upload anything and even if I could it has personal information in it which would risk my job, at best. So I cannot put the workbook somewhere to be viewed, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those that have helped,

The issue has been resolved as this was a corruption in my workbook.

Since this has been fixed (Moved everything into a new Excel document) my origional code is now working fine

Thanks to all those that helps

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understand now, the code below find the row number in Column C, where the name is identical co the name in Cell A7.

```
' find last row in Column C
last_row = Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

' find row number in column C where the name is identical to cell A7
row_found = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("A7"), Range("C1:C" & last_row), 0)
MsgBox " Name found at Cell C" & last_row
```

Comment: I think you have the columns and rows the wrong way round for `Cells` it should be `Cells(RowNum, ColNum)`, so `Cells(7,3)` is `[C7]`. I am also wanting to move down the rows and not move along the columns

Comment: you are right, allways getting them wrong when switching from cells to rows. So now I am really confused with the need to look for row 3 when he is slecting `Range("C7").Select` which is in row 7, did you understand where is he looking for the dates ?

Comment: I think there has been a bit of miscommunication, when starting at `[C7].select` I am checking A7 (`sName = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value`) for a persons name, it then needs to offset down the cells till it reachs that persons name. The problem is, is that `[C7].select` (or any other varation of .select) doesnt actually work (it runs past the code but doesnt execute it so no error message)

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. My workbook was corrupted so no matter what anyone posted it seems that my error wouldnt go away, I have tried you code on a uncorrupted version of the file and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking the question to be:-

It should run down the cells in column C looking at column A until it reaches the persons name (defined by sName), once it gets to that is will then exit the loop and continue with the rest of the code.

(The above is paraphrased from your question)

The code I am suggesting to replace is: -

```
[C7].Select
'Do Until ActiveCell.Row >= Finalrow
'drop out of loop if no more dates detected in row 3
Do Until sName = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

Replacing it with the below would fix the issue with minimal change: -

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(7, 3).Select
Do Until sName = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

However, using select is not recommended and if `sName` is not found this would keep going to the end of the sheet where it would throw an error referring to exceeding the maximum sheet size being exceeded.

I would suggest the below as a better replacement:-

```
Dim LngRow As Long
LngRow = 7
Do Until (ActiveSheet.Cells(LngRow, 1) = sName) Or (ActiveSheet.Cells(LngRow, 1) = "")
    LngRow = LngRow + 1
Loop
If ActiveSheet.Cells(LngRow, 1) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Pearson not found"
    Exit Sub
Else
    ActiveSheet.Cells(LngRow, 3).Select
End If
```

(I have placed `ActiveSheet.Cells(LngRow, 3).Select` at the end as your remaining code may rely on the cell being selected)

Comment: I have tried you code but the same issue happens at `Do Until (ActiveSheet.Cells(LngRow, 1) = sName) Or (ActiveSheet.Cells(LngRow, 1) = "")` however this appears to be no fault other than my own, after speaking to several other colleagues it was suggested that I try the same thing in another excel document, it turns out my excel document with the code has been corrupted to a lesser extent. your code posted is a great example on how to run through cells without using .select though

Comment: Once you fix the corruption does the above fix your issue, or does the fix corruption mean you have no issue?

Comment: Since the corruption has been fixed my origional code works fine.

Comment: I have tried your code on the uncorrupted version on the file and that worked fine (`Or (ActiveSheet.Cells(LngRow, 1) = "")` needed to be removed but thats because of the formatting in my workbook)